# Passing variable between php web page and a background script

Tags: php, session, background

I am trying to run a php script in the background on windows.

Im looking for a way to pass a variable between them. Basically thats what im trying to accomplish:

php page:

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['abc'] = 1 ;       
  $cmd = "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php -f c:\wamp\www\FinalProject\newEmptyPHP.php" ;  
  pclose(popen("start /B ".$cmd, 'r'));
  while ( $_SESSION['abc'] == 1)
  {
      sleep(1) ; 
  }
  echo 'Done';
```

background script:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['abc'] = 0 ;
```

Im open to any suggestions.

Comment: Windows is an OS, it is more likely that you are using PHP in a browser?

Comment: Take a look at PHP socket programming

Answer (score 0):

You should execute this passing the var as an argument on the console call:

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['abc'] = 1 ;
    $cmd = "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php -f c:\wamp\www\FinalProject\newEmptyPHP.php " . $_SESSION['abc'] ;  
    /** ... */
```

After that you will be able to get the argument from newEmptyPHP.php using $argv var (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

I think that you will never get your session updated in that way because:
1) PHP is not listening to external changes in $_SESSION during the execution. If it were possible, the would be a very difficult to maintain and debug. 2) The script in console will not be using the sessions as a session is only accessible by the client that opened it (see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)
But... Why do you need to call a PHP script from PHP using popen? It will be very slow. I recommend to build the feature you need to use from  newEmptyPHP.php inside your application.

Comment: basically  my goal is to run a exe file in the background and receive a signal when its done.

Comment: You can do that by reading the stream returned by popen [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php). Just take care that the background process is fast enough: it will lock PHP execution. Depending on what you need to do on the background, may be you should look for a solution different from PHP (NodeJS could be a good option).